# How to minimize the spaces (gap) between 28 ordered plots when using matrix layout in R?

Tags: r, plot

For my purposes, I only need to use a matrix layout (not `mfrow`, or `split.screen`).

I was wondering in a `7 x 4` layout for `28` *ordered plots* how could I minimize (I will not need any axes or axes labels, only the frame is enough) all the possible spaces between the 28 plots?

```
m = matrix(c(1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28), nrow = 7); layout(m)
par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))

lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution

```
m = matrix(c(1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28), nrow = 7);
layout(m)
par(mar = c(0.1, 0.1,0.1,0.1), oma=c(1,1,1,1))
lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
```

Play around with the margins a bit: c(0.1, 0.1,0.1,0.1) and increase/decrease values. the parameters xaxt and yaxt="n" suppress the axis ticks. oma is for the outer margins and adds space around the entire "frame".

Comment: look for nested plots. like (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817557/nested-plots-in-r] or (perhaps here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015449/nested-layouts-in-r]

Comment: sry, misread that. answer is updated. oma is the parameter that works